# Create default method for classes implementing the same interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

As a very simplistic example, suppose I have the following C# classes and code:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    public string MyData { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; }
}

public class BaseClass1 { }
public class BaseClass2 { }

public class ClassA : BaseClass1, IMyInterface
{
    public string MyData { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; private set; }

    public ClassA(string myData, int myValue)
    {
        MyData = myData;
        MyValue = myValue;
        // SAME, specific, code relating to my interface implementation
    }
}

public class ClassB : BaseClass2, IMyInterface
{
    public string MyData { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; private set; }

    public ClassB(string myData, int myValue)
    {
        MyData = myData;
        MyValue = myValue;
        // SAME, specific, code relating to my interface implementation
    }
}
```

So, `ClassA` and `ClassB` both implement the same interface and both have the same, boilerplate code they need to run - In this case, just simply setting the public properties (`MyData = myData;`...) for the interface they both implement and, because they already inherit from other, different classes, I can't create an abstract class to have them inherit from.

Obviously, this is a very simplistic example, but, supposing all of my implementing classes had some, very specific, boilerplate code they needed to run, how can I make it so that I only have to write the boilerplate code in one location and don't need to write the same code in each implementation?

Comment: sounds like you want to do multiple inheritance which isn't supported. why not have an internal static method to help?

Comment: C#8 has [default implementations in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/default-interface-methods-versions)

Comment: seems like a good place for abstract class

Comment: @Nonik, I can't do an abstract class since they both already inherit other classes.

Comment: @KlausGütter, I don't know how I could get what I want with default implementation - It feels like the right thing (that or composition), but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @DanielA.White, How would that work? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Could you use a generic base class that takes `BaseClass1` and `BaseClass2` as type parameters?

Comment: @AndrewH, I do suppose that could work, but it seems clunky if I ever need to add in, say `BaseClass3` for a different implementation - I'm really hoping there's a different way to do this based upon the interface or composition somehow. If not, I guess that's what I'll have to do (or just write the code in in each class)

Comment: I think the situation you're in doesn't really have an elegant, concise, and easily-maintainable solution. Some concessions will need to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a shared static method:

```
public static class YourHelper
{
   public static void Initialize(IMyInterface foo, ...) ...
}
```

Then from the `ClassA` and `ClassB` constructors, I would call this `Initialize` method.

```
public class ClassA : BaseClass1, IMyInterface
{
    public string MyData { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; private set; }

    public ClassA(string myData, int myValue)
    {
        MyData = myData;
        MyValue = myValue;
        MyHelper.Initalize(this, ...);
    }
}
```

I would avoid using default interface implementation because it would rely on virtual mechanisms and calling virtual stuff in a constructor is discouraged.

Comment: I apologize, Daniel, but I'm a bit confused how this could work, would my `ClassA` and `ClassB` go in as parameters to the `Initialize` function and, then, set their values there? Could you show how you would do it with just one of my classes, for example?

Comment: Gotcha - Thanks for the clarification. I hope there's a better way, but I can see how that would do the trick as well.